# Why does my computer have two default gateways?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Windows Vista computer and my internet cuts out intermittently. I did a ipconfig and I saw I had two default gateways.

One was a 192 and the second was a 68. I then logged in my router. I saw under DMZ that second default gateway (68) was listed but I could delete it or do any type of edit on it.

I went to my adapter “Settings > IPv4” and there was no configurations. So it was normal.

Why do I have two default gate ways? Is this a ISP thing or is there a way I can delete it?

Comment: please post the output of `route print` from an elevated command prompt or powershell instance.

Comment: Hi, I will soon but could you tell me what I might be looking for?

Comment: the route to the 68. network, the route(s) to 0.0.0.0, the exit interfaces on all of these, evidence of persistent routes, etc, etc. the routing table is the best way to look into the intricacies of how routes are configured and chosen at runtime. Note that the default gateway is by definition the lowest metric route to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause: multiple NICs.  For instance, wired (Ethernet) and wireless (Wi-Fi).  Maybe multiple "network adapters" including something like a VPN (not necessarily a physical card).

Under each adapter, TCP/IP settings, you can go to an Advanced options screen to add a default gateway.

Using "netstat -nr" is probably the best option (similar to "route print", though "netstat -nr" is a bit more compatible with different operating systems).  So then you can see what interface the traffic is sent out.

whois.arin.net will be able to tell you what organization is behind a specific IP address.  For instance, [ARIN report on 68.0.0.1](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-68-0-0-0-2/pft?s=68.0.0.1) says that address is Cox Communications (a cable company).